# Bootstrap 3 show next \ prev popup box?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

need help for this question.
i've been racking my brain over how to add next/ previous buttons to bootstrap popover.
There are some buttons that cause the popover standard properties.

```
data-toggle="popover" data-placement="top"
```

Thanx for help!

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with these buttons? Are they supposed to be inside the popover? Does clicking them make the next popover on the page show? Please be more specific.

Comment: Hi, Yony yes, after click button inside box, need preview next popop